# Two lines with edge corners

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I need some help. I would like to do two lines with edge corners but I am having a problem. The final result will be like this:

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzoLI.png)

[image]

I did some draft and I think that I am in the right way.

HTML:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
  width: 48%;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  float: left;
  left:0;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  border-top: 0.2rem solid; 
  border-right: 0.2rem solid;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right:0;
  border-top: 0.2rem solid;
  border-left: 0.2rem solid;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
```

You can see the same code on codepen.io. Follow the [link](http://codepen.io/pedroramus/pen/YwXQLr)

I think it is not in the center.

Comment: @Harry
Yes, I did. I was trying too solve my problem. But you solve my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `transform-origin` for both the `.left` and `.right` elements, change their width to be less than 50% (by half the border width).

The `transform-origin` property specifies the point or axis about which the transform should happen. Here the `.left` element should be skewed such that its bottom-right point remains fixed and `.right` element should be skewed such that its bottom-left point remains fixed. Hence, we give those values to the `transform-origin` property.

For `width` when we give `50%` as the value and then add a `border` also to it, the actual width of the element becomes more than 50% (it becomes 50% + 0.2rem) because border is generally not part of the element's width. You can change this by modifying the `box-sizing` property of the elements or by reducing the `width`. Here, we reduce it only by half of the border's width because, the borders should overlap.

```
.left {
  width: calc(50% - 0.1rem); /* change this */
  /* other properties from your code */
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right; /* add this */
}

.right {
  width: calc(50% - 0.1rem); /* change this */
  /* other properties from your code */
  transform-origin: bottom left; /* add this */
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.618em;
  color: #454545;
}

.left {
  width: calc(50% - 0.1rem);
  padding-top: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  float: left;
  left:0;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  border-top: 0.2rem solid; 
  border-right: 0.2rem solid;
}

.right {
  width: calc(50% - 0.1rem);
  padding-top: 2rem;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right:0;
  border-top: 0.2rem solid;
  border-left: 0.2rem solid;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

---

Below is a slightly more tuned version which produces the same output. The following are the tunings that were done:

- Removed floats from both elements as they are not required.
- Added relative position to wrapper and positioned child elements absolutely with respect to it.
- Added `overflow: hidden` on parent to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing.
- Nullified left and right margin of `body` to make sure the line goes from one end to another.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.618em;
  color: #454545;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 0.2rem solid; 
  border-right: 0.2rem solid;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 0.2rem solid;
  border-left: 0.2rem solid;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Harry. Look there in codepen. I am new in css. Can you share a pen or jsfiddle. Thanks

Comment: You can look. Nice, buddy. I am apreciate your help.

Comment: I am new here in stack, so I don't know how to use properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.left {
  width: 48.5%;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  float: left;
  left:0;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  border-top: 0.2rem solid; 
  border-right: 0.2rem solid;
}

.right {
  width: 48.5%;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right:0;
  border-top: 0.2rem solid;
  border-left: 0.2rem solid;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
```